# How to prevent overflow when using a Column in SliverFillRemaining

Tags: flutter, customscrollview

I am facing an issue implementing a `CustomScrollView`. Check out [this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=dfd57b0cbf09f6e576ffc9f554388473) to see the problem I am facing (works best on wide screens). The behaviour is exactly as I want it to be, but I do not know how to fix the overflow issues.

The UI that I am trying to go for is very similar to [this example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html#:%7E:text=This%20example%20shows%20a%20NestedScrollView) using the `NestedScrollView`, with some sort of collapsing `FlexibleSpace` and a TabBar. However, I want some content (purple in the DartPad) above the `TabBar` that remains in view even once the `FlexibleSpace` is collapsed entirely, and I cannot use the `SliverAppBar` widget because the 'bottom' parameter should implement `PreferredSizeWidget` and my purple content does not have a fixed size. I cannot change my `Column` to a `ListView` either because then I can't use the `Flexible` for the text content.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to pin the purple content with dynamic height and then the TabBar after that?

Comment: I might use `CustomScrollView` inside the TabBarView instead of  on top level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I recommend you use this package [ExtendedNestedScrollView](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_nested_scroll_view): Since there is a `TabBarView` that contains another scroll on each Tab, so you can't use `CustomScrollView` if you need a RefreshIndicator to refresh the content in each tab. If you use `CustomScrollView` you can only put **one** `RefreshIndicator` globally to refresh all Tab. The package I referenced will make you more customizable to add the `RefreshIndicator` to each `TabBarView`.

About the purple content, that pinned and dynamically height.
You can try to look into this

[Is there a way to achieve a dynamic height in bottom widget of SliverAppBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268040/is-there-a-way-to-achieve-a-dynamic-height-in-bottom-widget-of-sliverappbar)

[How can I get the height of a widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-a-widget)

There is no simple way to achieve the dynamic pinned sliver. There are several answers there that might help you

Comment: I do not need RefreshIndicator's, but thank you for linking the other answers, its seems that I do need to know the height to make this work.